# How can I import a .css-file which is in the same folder as my React-component?

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I import a .css-file which is in the same folder as my React-component. I have the following 2 files in the same folder.

File `Navbar.css`

```
.navbar-div {
  ...
}
```

File `Navbar.jss`

```
import styles from './Navbar.css'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.navbar-div}>
      <table>
        <row>
        ...
```

Importing of the css-stles does not work. The error message is:

```
src/components/Navbar.js
  Line 5:31:  'div' is not defined  no-undef
```

I have found a lot of examples with this exact approach that seem to work. Obviously, I did something wrong but I could not figure out what it is. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions!

Comment: import './Navbar.css'

Comment: Are you using Webpack? If so, are you using [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/)?

Comment: And then `<div className="navbar-div">`

Comment: I tried `import './Navbar.css'`. Unfortunately, it does not work. I get even more errors.

Comment: I would like to try Webpack and I have installed `css-loader`. Where do I have to "activate" that npm-module and where and how do I use it to import my styles?

Answer (score 0):

Change your css filename to Navbar.module.css and change this `<div style={styles.navbar-div}>` to `<div className={styles.navbar-div}>`. Now it will work.

Know more: [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

Import it like this:

```js
import './Navbar.css'
```

in your `navbar.jsx` and it should work ([sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIsIw.png)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).